# Hibernate turns my uuid to empty byte array

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, uuid

Im an intern at another company so i don't have full insight about the inner workings of their hibernate implementation. All i know is:
dialect: SQLServerDialect 
connection driver class:net.sf.log4jdbc.DriverSpy 
And the database is a 2014 sql server microsoft

If there is anything else required please leave a comment

That being said here is what i have done:

Moved all test that uses hibernate into a seperate project for tests. 
To see if the hibernate still worked i tried a test where i create and persist a entity. 
This has cause a strange error where my UUID gets turned and stored as a empty byte array and stored with a default uuid instead. This means the second time i run it it will say that the UUID already exists because it has (again) reverted to a default value. 
Here is a sample of the code i want to run

```
EntityManager em = DBService.getInstance().getDefaultEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    Invoice o = new Invoice();
    System.out.println("real id " +o.getId().toString());
    em.persist(o);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    assertFalse(em.find(Invoice.class, o.getId()) == null);
```

Here is the values that is used, The last one is primary uuid

```
values ('03/02/2015 15:14:04.038', NULL, NULL, NULL, 
0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0,  NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, 0, 25.0, '<byte[]>')
```

Here is the SYSO with the real uuid:

```
real id 578AF113-AA51-4A0C-9FD1-31DE9A820DA4
```

Here is the exception thrown

```
ExceptionHelper:146 - Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__Invoice__3213E83F25AF783C'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Invoice'. The duplicate key value is (0500edac-7273-2400-636f-6d2e6d696e75).
```

Comment: Some information on the mapping would be nice, especially how the id property is mapped.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the post as NHibernate, not Hibernate.  They may be the same answer, but I don't want to answer on a framework I seldom use.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by moving my uuid typedef mapping java class to the test project because apparently the two projects couldn't share it.